# Procedure in SQL (Oracle) for two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, procedure

I have a small tricky problem here. I have 2 tables:

```
employee(id,salary,bonus) 
employee_performance(id,gain,year) .
```

I'm trying to change the bonus on table `employee`, according to performance using a procedure.

This is that I have done so far:

```
create or replace procedure name_of_proc 
AS
BEGIN
   update employee e
      set e.bonus = e.bonus - 900
   where e.salary >= 2000 
     and employee_performance.gain <=2000 
     and employee_performance.year = 2012 
     and e.id=employee_performance.id;
END;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to put into the procedure the table `employee_performance`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
create or replace procedure name_of_proc 
AS
BEGIN
   update employee e
      set e.bonus = e.bonus - 900
   where e.salary >= 2000 
     and e.id in 
         (select ep.id from employee_performance ep where ep.gain <=2000 
          and ep.year = 2012
          and ep.id = e.id
         );
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, this error comes though --> Error(9,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: Missing Expression

Comment: I think I found it thanks, you did put one more and that didn't need